# Removal of CMB signal

Tags: cosmic-microwave-background

How would it be possible to remove the Cosmic Microwave Background signal from the electric circuit powering up a Tesla motors car engine?

Comment: There's a CMB signal coming from a Tesla?

Answer (score 2):

The CMB peaks at about 160 GHz, and most of the power density is between 300 MHz and 300 GHz. I don't know what is the frequency range used in the Tesla, but I seriously doubt is at those high frequencies in the millimeter wave range. If true most of that won't make it into the circuits.

Even if the Tesla has some key circuits in that frequency range, which again I doubt, the CMB is so weak it won't make a difference.

What does make it in, i.e., whatever power density there is in the frequency range of the circuits, and the wires, will be Gaussian noise-like. If tHe Tesla circuits/wires bandwidth is large enough so you can detect the slope of the power density on them, being smart by offsetting the circuit freq response as well as the CMB slope. But since the phase is random you won't be able to do any coherent cancellation, just some power equalization. If over the Tesla's bandwidth the power density is close enough to white, you cannot do anything, it's just like random white noise.

Scientists have not found a non-Gaussianity in the CMB, but they are looking, and if they find any you'd be able to use the correlations, but meanwhile there's nothing coherent you can do, only power equalization with some equalizing filters in the circuits

I doubt it will make any difference to anything at all in the Tesla, the power density will just be too low. You can just ignore it.