# CMB free containment area for proposed experiments

Tags: cosmic-microwave-background

Could someone please help me? I would like to have a method whereby I can do experiments I have in mind involving a purpose built container of dimensions of at least a foot cubed or it can be larger if easier to built it bigger. My aim is to remove from inside this container all trace of the CMB signal for at least ten minutes at a time or longer is fine. For some reason I am wondering if the containment area might work if made of Kevlar? Most important is a clear description of how to cancel out the CMB signal. Thank you in advance for your time and expertise from Marc.

Comment: You have to keep in mind that all masses radiate with their black body radiation, so you cannot have a radiation free space inside the box, even if you exclude the incoming.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/331224/2451

Answer (score 1):

The cosmic microwave photons are observed with metal dishes. They reflect off metal. So you just need to enclose your experiment in a metal box.